# Fit header image in mobile header menu

Tags: image, mobile, menu, header, graphical-logo

How can I make this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxyqE.png) fit the mobile header menu? I also want to make it larger as you can barely see what's written below the logo.

**The image should stay in its place on the desktop version - I am satisfied with how it looks**

[Website for reference](http://semdesculpas.org/)

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all.. Is this done with bootstrap, or something, or did you make it from scratch?

The problem is, your "nav" is 100% wide, taking all the space to the left. Also, your header-image-wrap div is 100% wide, as well. Therefore, they can only fit one underneath another.

You need to change your code. In mobile view, navigation doesn't need to take all that space. It should only be a size of a hamburger menu. If it's bootstrap, find a nav bar that has logo on it, and make a mobile logo image, or change the default design. I don't think there's a practical solution for this one.. As far as my knowledge goes...

As far as the size of an image go, you need to make another one, for mobile view, if you want bigger letters and stuff. You can't really change this one with css.